# How to create separate admin domain

Tags: php

I want to make this feature on our site, but I don't know what to search and how to do it.
For example I have a site named [www.abcd.com](http://www.abcd.com). That site is only for users but for admin, I want to have a site named [www.admin.abcd.com](http://www.admin.abcd.com). I hope you can help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: You have to clarify a little bit. Does your page have an admin backend (like wordpress: abcd.com/wp-admin) or do you mean with "for admin" when an admin user is logged in?

Comment: I mean that when the admin wants to change something or add something in the website, he would need to go to admin.abcd.com, and not in the user domain

Comment: Just create a virtual host for the subdomain?

Comment: How to do this depends on how your site is hosted and has nothing to do with PHP. Are you on shared hosting with cPanel? There's probably a screen where you can define subdomains. Hosting your own server? Then start by reading the docs for your webserver (e.g. Apache, IIS, nginx or whatever)